# How to setup visual studio 2012 project to IIS

Tags: visual-studio-2012, iis, installation

I recently started creating a web application project which I need to setup or configure to IIS. I don't have any idea how but I've tried to search google but can't seem to find a way to make it work. Do you have any tutorials that could help me or provide any instructions like from start to finish? Thanks a lot.

Comment: To better guide you, we need additional information about your hosting setup.  Do you have administrative access to the server hosting IIS? Which architecture are you using asp.net we forms or MVC?  What operating system is IIS running on e.g. Win 2008 R2 or 2012?

Comment: I do have administrative access on IIS and have asp.net web forms here and I'm using windows 8.1 as my operating system. Thanks.